# How can I use `tokio::spawn` in a third-party crate that does not implement the `Send` trait?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

The struct named `ResultSet` from the Oracle crate does not implement the `Send` trait. But the definition of `tokio::spawn` requires that the result of the future it spawns implements the `Send` trait. Do I have to modify the `ResultSet` struct to implement `Send`? Is there a better way?

```
pub fn query_named(
    &self,
    sql: &str,
    params: &[(&str, &dyn ToSql)],
) -> Result<ResultSet<Row>, Error>{
    let rows = self.conn.query_named(sql, params)?;
    Ok(rows)
}

pub async fn translate_result(
    rm_result: Vec<sqlserver_mod2::MyResult>,
) -> Result<String, Error> {
    let res_get_ryxm = ordb.query_named(sql_getRYXM, &[("barcode", &"900421757188")]).unwrap();
    otherfun(res_get_ryxm);
}

spawn(async {
    translate_result().await;
});
```

Comment: If the type cannot safely be moved between threads, then you are out of luck. The automatic decision made by the compiler is most likely correct, if not you should open an issue with the `oracle` crate.

BTW, you could always just use another, more generic, crate instead of the Oracle one.

Comment: Thanks,but i cant find better oracle orm in rust,any recommended？

Comment: Oh sorry, you are probably right, Oracle doesn't seem to be very widely supported (for good reason, but that's besides the point). Seems like you have to keep the `ResultSet` on one thread / task without moving it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`tokio::task::spawn_local`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.spawn_local.html) if your async code is executing in the context of a [`LocalSet`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/struct.LocalSet.html):

```
use std::future::Future;
use std::pin::Pin;
use tokio::task::LocalSet;

// This is explicitly a !Send future
fn f() -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = ()>>> {
    Box::pin(async {
        println!("hey, it worked");
        // can use spawn_local() here
    })
}

// This creates a multi-threaded runtime
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let local = LocalSet::new();
    local.run_until(f()).await;
}
```

However, be sure to heed its documentation since there are many restrictions for where it can be used since it goes against the grain of tokio's blocking and work-stealing model.

---

If this would be used extensively throughout your code-base, you may opt to use [actix-rt](https://crates.io/crates/actix-rt) instead of using tokio directly:

> Tokio-based single-threaded async runtime for the Actix ecosystem.
>
> In most parts of the the Actix ecosystem, it has been chosen to use `!Send` futures. For this reason, a single-threaded runtime is appropriate since it is guaranteed that futures will not be moved between threads. This can result in small performance improvements over cases where atomics would otherwise be needed.
>
> To achieve similar performance to multi-threaded, work-stealing runtimes, applications using `actix-rt` will create multiple, mostly disconnected, single-threaded runtimes. This approach has good performance characteristics for workloads where the majority of tasks have similar runtime expense.